# How can I get users full name session data in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a login page where user submit his password and email. he would redirect to index page and there will be display user FUll name.

```
include_once 'db.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email='" . escape($email) . "' AND active = 1;
    $result = query($sql);
    if (row_count($result) == 1){
        $row = fetch_array($result);

        $db_passpord = $row['password'];

        $db_name = $row['full_name'];

        if (md5($password) == $db_passpord) {

            if ($remember == "on") {
                setcookie('email', $email, time() + 86460);
            }
            $_SESSION['fullname'] = $db_name;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

`$_SESSION['full_name'];` It will display the username which is used. I want to display the Name of user name what is in database. There is a row in database named full_name I used $db_name to set row['full_name'].

Comment: Please reconsider this application, there are multiple security issues (and PHP syntax issues). To answer your question though select more than just `password, id`.

Comment: This code won't even compile. I doubt very much that the OP actually uses this code.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this isn't the actual code on the website since there are a number of errors present.

```
include_once 'db.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $email= mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']));

    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email='".escape($email)."' AND active = 1;

    $result = query($sql);

    if(row_count($result) == 1)
    {
        $row = fetch_array($result);

        $db_passpord = $row['password'];

        $db_name = $row['full_name'];

        if(md5($password) == $db_passpord)
        {
            if($remember == "on") 
                setcookie('email',$email, time() + 86460);

            $_SESSION['fullname'] = $db_name;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There are no quotes around the select statement, I'm guessing that the included DB.PHP file has with in it the functions "query" and "fetch_array", else they do not exist.

You are saying that the "echo $_SESSION['full_name']" does not display the full name, but your code is setting the full name to "$_SESSION['fullname']".

Comment: `$db_name` is set to `$row['full_name']` though and `full_name` is not selected so likely that is the root of the issue. Multiple issues though.

Comment: @user3783243 do I need to SELECT full_name?

Comment: @CodePlay Yes, you only get back what you tell it to **SELECT**.